# Pexect in Windows Batch File > Cygwin > Python > SSH

Tags: python, windows, cygwin, cisco, pexpect

I have a Linux box that runs Cisco IOS and need to SSH into it sometimes to reboot it.  I've written a batch file that calls on Cygwin.  Cygwin then calls on Python+PythonScript.

Batch File:

```
cd c:\cygwin64\bin
bash --login -i -c "python3 /home/Owner/uccxtesting.py"
```

Python Script

```
import pexpect
import time
import sys

server_ip = "10.0.81.104"
server_user = "administrator"
server_pass = "secretpassword"

sshuccx1 = pexpect.spawn('ssh %s@%s' % (server_user, server_ip))
sshuccx1.logfile_read = sys.stdout.buffer
sshuccx1.timeout = 180
sshuccx1.expect('.*password:')
sshuccx1.sendline(server_pass)
sshuccx1.expect('.admin:')
sshuccx1.sendline('utils system restart')
sshuccx1.expect('Enter (yes/no)?')
sshuccx1.sendline('yes')
time.sleep(30)
```

When I run this, it stops at `Enter yes/no`.  This is what I'm getting:

[image]

I've seen plenty of examples of pexpect with expect, but there is some white space out beside the question mark. I just don't know how to tell python to expect it.

Comment: does it work if you run the python script from Mintty ?

Comment: I get the same thing

Comment: How can I modify the sshuccx1.expect('Enter (yes/no)?') line so if the line contains "yes/no" it'll pick that up?   I've tried doing sshuccx1.expect('.*yes.*')  but it fails to pick that up.

Comment: are you sure the python and ssh are the Cygwin ones ?

Comment: Yes when I installed Cygwin, I picked to install python from its installation wizard.

Comment: Is there a way to expect anything, then give it yes?  Or is there a way to wait x amount of seconds then issue another command?  I've tried the later one but the script just terminates.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a bug:

**utils system restart prompts for force restart** (https://bst.cisco.com/bugsearch/bug/CSCvw22828)

Replace `time.sleep(30)` with the following code to answer a possible `force restart` prompt. If it works, you can get rid of the `try...except` and `print` commands that I added for debugging:

```
try:
    index = -1
    while index != 0:
        sshuccx1.expect_exact(['succeeded', 'force', ], timeout=300)
        if index == 2:
            print('Forcing restart...')
            sshuccx1.sendline('yes')
    print('Operation succeeded')
    print(str(child.before))
except pexpect.ExceptionPexpect:
    e_type, e_value, _ = sys.exc_info()
    print('Error: ' + pexpect.ExceptionPexpect(e_type).get_trace())
    print(e_type, e_value)
```

Also, change `sshuccx1.expect('Enter (yes/no)?')` to `sshuccx1.expect_exact('Enter (yes/no)?')`. The `expect` method tries to match a regex pattern, and it may get caught on the parentheses (see https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pexpect.html#pexpect.spawn.expect_exact)